# Can I replace this keypad with an Arduino / Raspberry Pi GPIO

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, gpio, keypad

I need to replace the keypad from this board with a Raspberry Pi or Arduino so I can control programmatically what keys are sent to the board (so I can automate keypad press, without having the physical keypad connected).

- Can I just connect GPIOs (3.3 V) from a Raspberry to the socket board (in image #3) directly, so it can act as a keypad but programmatically?  I'm afraid to fry the board.
- Why are there 10 pins? Most keypads I have seen only have 7 pins.

[image: #1 Keypad] [image: #2 Back of the keypad]

[image: The other end of the wire band where it is connected to the board] [image: HD picture of the board]

[image: HD picture of the board (under)]

Thanks for your help

Comment: seven relays ... one for each row and column ... close one column and one row to assert a keypress

Comment: This is the plan I m gonna end up with yeah, thanks

Comment: I have succeeded to identify which pin is which col/row and was able to trigger numbers  with my breadboard. I just have now to find relays to do it automatically

Comment: optoisolators may also work

Answer (score 3):

Unlikely, or it depends if you can figure it out yourself if you can or can not, as it may or may not be possible for various reasons.

The other board looks like has a programmable microcontroller, so it is scanning the keypad matrix. The connector may have 10 pins instead of 7 for various reasons. The matrix may or may not be arranged as a 3x4 matrix. The other pins might be unused or used for something, like ground, chassis, earth, or backlight or whatever. It is unknown until you figure out how the 10 pins are used.

Even if it just a 3x4 matrix, you don't know how it is scanned until you test it. It might be a part of a larger matrix. You also don't know if the matrix is scanned with 5V or 3.3V or some other voltage, until you figure it out.

Even if you figure it out, the speed how the matrix is scanned is also unknown, so it may be difficult to write software which reacts to correct scan outputs fast enough to simulate a button push. Might be especially hard with Raspberry Pi since it does not run a real time OS. Might be possible with Arduino if most of the time is spent responding to the scanned matrix pins, instead of other stuff.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I ve added 2 more pictures that seems to show that only 7 pins are actually connected to the board. If it's not possible, do you have any ideas how I could automate what keys are sent? The micro controller is a PRO-328-P

Comment: It still might be possible, if you have not done anything to confirm it either is or is not possible, since you have the board, we don't. PRO-328-P is not a microcontroller. It might be a name of some board with some microcontroller and other stuff, the name could indicate it has an ATMega328 or some variant.

Comment: And what if I recreate the matrix pad but instead of using buttons, I use 3v relays that I can control with the arduino? and let the initial board send the signals for each column and use the arduino to open/close the correct row relay to let the signal through

Comment: That's of course possible, but going around the original problem if it is possible directly. The relays don't have to be 3V relays. And analog multiplexer or analog switch ICs are quite a bit cheaper and consume much less current than relays. So you could use relays, but it might not be the smallest or easiest or cheapest solution.

Comment: Thank you, I m gonna try with 2x [74HC4066](https://www.eleccircuit.com/74hc4066-quad-analog-switch-cmos-data-sheet/) since they have 4 controllable switches with input/ouput

Comment: @Owow Then you are back to square one, thinking if the voltages between ICs are compatible or not, so it may or may not work. It would be just better if you would measure the circuit to find out if you can use 74HC4066 directly and at what supply voltage.

Comment: Since 74HC4066 just let the input flow to the output, why should I care about voltage? I tried putting a led between the keypad and the board and it barely light up so it's probably low voltage enough anyway @Justme

Comment: @Owow You should care. Because if the keyboard signals are 5V, the 74HC4066 when powered from 3.3V can't handle 5V signals and may damage. If you power the 74HC4066 from 5V so it can handle the matrix signal voltage, then your Rapberry Pi with 3.3V GPIO can't control the 74HC4066 because it then is not compatible with 3.3V control signals as it needs 5V control signals.

Comment: Unfortunately you were right and it is 5V. What can I use then to open/close columns/rows with a raspberry (which only sends 3.3 V on its GPIOs)? @Justme

Comment: With a mux that can work with 5V supply and switching signals and 3.3V control. Try HCT instead of HC or level shift the control signals for the HC with something like the HCT.

Comment: I m having a hard time finding the correct one to use. From what I understand, it's called a QUAD ANALOG SWITCH, but I need it to accept 5v while letting me activate the switches with 3.3 V? is that right? Any advice on how to find the correct one? @Justme

Comment: I have just ordered some [TXS0108E](https://protosupplies.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/TXS0108E-8-Channel-Logic-Level-Shifter-Connections.jpg) to shift my GPIOS outputs from 3.3v to 5v so I can operate the switches on 74HC4066. Will let you know how it goes

Comment: @Owow TXS0108 is way over what you need, but it just might work in this case. Generally, if you look at questions here about it, people use that high-end level shifter outside recommended operating conditions and then they have problems with it  even in basic circuits.

Comment: This is the final plan: https://i.imgur.com/zz8dmhd.png